# Generate all combinations from multiple lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, permutation

I have a dataset which contains multiple lists each having different number of elements. For eg.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']

list2 = ['d','e']

list3 = ['f','g','h','i']
```

I want to generate all possible unique combinations from these lists with the following conditions:

1. The number of elements in one combination should be 5
2. Minimum of 1 element from each list.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: try `itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it (a lot of these steps could be combined but keeping them in to show steps)

Create a new list with all items in

```
list4 = list1 + list2 + list3
```

And another list to iterate through them to find all 5 combinations (you didn't specify about order or replacement so have a read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and change as necessary)

```
list5 = list(itertools.combinations(list4, 5))
```

Then remove the items that don't have an element from each list.

```
[i for i in list5 if any(j in list1 for j in i) and any(j in list2 for j in i) and any(j in list3 for j in i)]
```

So in one line it could be:

```
[i for i in itertools.combinations(list1 + list2 + list3, 5) if any(j in list1 for j in i) and any(j in list2 for j in i) and any(j in list3 for j in i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I support [@Ghost Ops](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16693888/ghost-ops)'s answer.

`itertools.product` gave me the result I was looking for & in the easiest way.

Example:

```py
from itertools import product

Suit = [u"\u2666", u"\u2665", u"\u2663", u"\u2660"]
Card = ['A','K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2']
FullDeck = list(product(Card, Suit))

for i in FullDeck:
    print(i)
```

Which Returns:

```
('A', '♦')
('A', '♥')
('A', '♣')
('A', '♠')
('K', '♦')
('K', '♥')
('K', '♣')
('K', '♠')
('Q', '♦')
('Q', '♥')
('Q', '♣')
('Q', '♠')
('J', '♦')
('J', '♥')
('J', '♣')
('J', '♠')
('10', '♦')
('10', '♥')
('10', '♣')
('10', '♠')
('9', '♦')
('9', '♥')
('9', '♣')
('9', '♠')
('8', '♦')
('8', '♥')
('8', '♣')
('8', '♠')
('7', '♦')
('7', '♥')
('7', '♣')
('7', '♠')
('6', '♦')
('6', '♥')
('6', '♣')
('6', '♠')
('5', '♦')
('5', '♥')
('5', '♣')
('5', '♠')
('4', '♦')
('4', '♥')
('4', '♣')
('4', '♠')
('3', '♦')
('3', '♥')
('3', '♣')
('3', '♠')
('2', '♦')
('2', '♥')
('2', '♣')
('2', '♠')
```

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question but is exactly what I was looking for. So, thanks.